# DotNetBrowser Rpc Call Timed Out

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

We recently upgraded from the 1.x version of the DotNetBrowser control to 2.1 and during regression testing, we ran into a new exception in our Citrix environment and we are unable to display the browser. We are using a BrowserView and have set the RenderingMode to Offscreen as well as set the UserDataDirectory when creating the engine in an attempt to eliminate potential Citrix specific issues.

Are there any special considerations we should make in a Citrix environment? Just looking for a little nudge in the right direction.

Thanks!

````
    [] has encountered an unexpected error.
You can continue but it is suggested that you do not save over your
 originally loaded projects to prevent data loss.
Details:
    RPC call timed out.

Stack Trace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at DotNetBrowser.Util.TaskExtensions.WaitResult[T](Task`1 task)
   at DotNetBrowser.Engine.EngineRpcService..ctor(IConnection connection, IEngineFactoryCommands factoryCommands, IEngineCommands commands, IRpcCallbacksStub`2 callbacks, ProprietaryFeatures proprietaryFeatures, RenderingMode renderingMode)
   at DotNetBrowser.Engine.EngineRpcService..ctor(EngineFactoryRpcService factoryCommands, ProprietaryFeatures proprietaryFeatures, RenderingMode renderingMode)
   at [].BrowserEngineBuilder.BuildEngine(String licenseKey) in ...
   at [].IntegralOrchestrator.get_BrowserEngine() in ...
   at [].UI.BrowserWindow.InitializeChromiumPlugin() in ...
   at [].UI.BrowserWindow..ctor() in ...
   at [].IntegralOrchestrator.ShowBrowser() in ...
   at [].Services.DockPanelPresentation.UI.MenuItem.MenuButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ...
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)```
````

Comment: Are you sure you have access to the targeted system, ports, IP's, Firewalls, etc?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes. This is an existing application, and we had the 1.x version of the DotNetBrowser control running without error previously. It could be our implementation of the Creation of the engine. The differences between 1.x and 2.x were rather large and we could have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular instance, setting SandboxDisabled to true worked. Thanks to the support team for suggesting that.

https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/gs/chromium.html#sandbox